# using os.system() to run a command without root

Tags: python, root, python-2.x

I have a python 2 script that is run as root. I want to use `os.system("some bash command")` without root privileges, how do I go about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use `os.seteuid(some_user_id)` before `os.system("some bash command")`.

Comment: how do i decide which userId to choose? what are my options?

Comment: It depends on the purpose of your script. `nobody` can be a good choice.

Answer (score -1):

I have test on my PC. If you run the python script like 'sudo test.py' and the question is resolved.